# how to know when Handler finished working

Tags: java, android, handler

I have read about Handler and understand what it does but I need something beyond it.

I have a game application with a button. I would like to wait a few second before changing the image on button, it does wait - but the problem is that the next line of code (PART 3) starts running without waiting for "DELAY" to end.

```
public sumMethod () {
    ////////// Long lines of code
    //////    PART 1  !!!!!!

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {  
            allBt[x] [y].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"none");
        )}   
    }, 3000);    //// DELAY

    //////// more line of code calling many other methods  PART 3 !!!!!
}
```

I have been thinking of working with boolean flag with while, but the apps get stuck in an infinite loop.

Can anyone help me out or tell me how to wait? In other words: How do I wait for the Handler to finish?

Comment: `i read about Handler and understand what it does ...` no, you do not ... `I have been thinking of working with boolean flag with while ... how to wait` bad, bad idea ... especially when sumMethod was called on Main thread (fx from onClick of view - you will get ANR)... halnder will finish it work just after setImageResource call(inside run method of inlined Runnable implementation) ... in other words put PART 3 inside run method ...

Comment: isnt there any other way ? its very complicated doing this in my code,

Comment: yes, there is an **idiots's way** 1. add field `private isFinished = false;` 2. before postDelayed put `isFinished = false;`  3. after `allBt[x] [y]...` inside run put `isFinished = true;` and 4. before PART 3  add `while(!isFinished) { Thread.sleep(10); }` ... as i said **only idiots will do this** ... normal way it to put the PART 3 inside run() ... but it's your choice ...

Comment: Why not simply wrap PART 3 into a method and call it inside `run()`?

Comment: Becuase i playing against computer, and the computer method for thinking is diffrent

Comment: Then I think you need to explain more in depth what you want to do. You want PART 3 to run after the button delay, but you do not want to wait for it?

Comment: this is how it looks



MainMethod
{

method1  ----i would like to wait inside


method2   --- computer thinks & play and call again to method 1


 --- if for next level to --- method3

}


now where sould my  HANDLER GO ?

Comment: Still not a clear question dude - depends on what you want to wait for. If it is the computation of the computer playing, then look into defining a callback, then you can know exactly when the computation is done instead of 'guessing' with a static delay

Comment: @Selvin only idiots would do this way since it doesn't work: if you are looping in while (!isFinished) the main Looper will never handle the delayed Runnable

Comment: MY PROBLEM IS IF I USE handler FOR "BLOCK OF COMMANDS" THE COMPUTER PLAY WITH ALL HIS UNITS BECAUSE THE RETURN FROM FOR LOOP delays.